# Como usar PostgreSQL com Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql

Eu tenho um sistema que estou desenvolvendo em C# WPF utilizando o PostgreSQL como SGBD e queria utilizar esse mesmo banco de dados para minha aplicação em ASP.NET MVC.

É possível fazer com que o Entity Framework tenha acesso aos dados que estão no SGBD PostgreSQL para poder utilizar os mesmos na minha aplicação em ASP.NET MVC?

Como é possível realizar a conexão entre o Entity Framework e o PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sim, só isso que queria saber?

Comment: E qual é a melhor maneira para fazer isso?

Comment: Aí eu teria que escrever um livro pra te responder,

Comment: Então como posso realizar essa conexão entre o entity e o SGBD do PostGres?

Comment: O problema é esse, vou ter que explicar tudo como o EF funciona para você entender.

Comment: Certo, então, onde posso encontrar links, livros, videos ou algo de referente para resolver esse problema ?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework/info